# Can this be considered a definition of $e$?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

Let $z$ be a complex number of the form $a + bi$ such that $a , b \in \mathbb{R}$. So, we can express $z$ as 
$$z = | z |(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$$

where $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan \left(\frac{b}{a} \right)$. Using Euler's formula, we can express 
$$\cos \theta + i\sin \theta = e^{i \theta}$$

So, substituting the value of $\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ in first equation, we get
$$z = |z|e^{i \theta}$$
$$e = \left (\frac{z}{|z|} \right )^{\frac{1}{i \theta}}$$

So, one can define $e$ as the ratio of $i \theta^{th}$ root of any complex number and its absolute value. Is this definition correct?

Comment: How  do you define the *iθ* th root?

Comment: Can you specify the exact mathematical meaning of $i\theta$th root?

Comment: Well, this can work by means of the complex logarithm...but this guy is sometimes a bad beast and we'll have to choose some reasonable branch of it and stuff. I think nobody, and in particular you and I, want to go there.

Comment: @DonAntonio So if we somehow manage to define what $i \theta^{th}$ root means, would it be considered a formal definition of $e$?

Comment: @unknownCoder Well, normal it will definitively not be, as the more usual *or normal* definitions are already in use for loooong time.

Comment: The main issue is that both $a^b$ and $\sqrt[b]{a}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^+$ are usually defined through the exponential function and its inverse function, $$ a^b = \exp(b\log a) $$ so your "definition" relying on a strange-th root is quite doomed to be a circular argument.